# Redimensionar imagem antes de enviar pro servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tela no meu aplicativo que faço upload de algumas imagens.

Até então estava tudo ok.

O usuário envia a imagem, tem a opção de "cortar ela" e aí sim envia para o servidor.

Só que, agora, testando no ios isso não funciona..

Fui pesquisar sobre e cheguei a conclusão que o erro é que no iOS tem problema de memória limitada, quando você está cortando uma imagem grande (resolução da câmera IPhone) uma tela será gerada com as dimensões da área de corte e, em seguida, ele irá gerar uma imagem com as dimensões cortadas dadas.

Durante este processo, o navegador trava.

Logo, gostaria de saber se é possível redimensionar a imagem (algo abaixo de 1000px) no próprio javaScript/jQuery e aí sim enviar para o servidor?